# Why use `useTable` over `ReactTable` when using react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, react-hooks, react-table

On their [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table), the example shows the usage of `<ReactTable>` component:

```
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
...
render() {
  return (
    <ReactTable
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
    />
  )
}
```

However, on their [API Docs](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/api.md) and [examples](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples), they all use `useTable`.

```
import { useTable } from 'react-table';

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data,
  })

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map(
          (row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                })}
              </tr>
            )}
        )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

...

render () {
  return (
    <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
  )
}
```

**So, my question is: Why would someone use hooks(useTable, useFilters, and etc...) and make Table component when he/she can just use a  that's already provided.
I'm pretty sure they didn't forget updating their npm page's example... or did they?**

Comment: The npm page says "This documentation is for [version 6](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6) of react-table." So the github link on the npm page is not correct. You will get version 6 when you do `yarn add react-table` because the version 7 is not released yet.

Comment: react-table v7 is not yet a release candidate which is why they haven't yet fully advertised it in npm. At the bottom of the NPM page you can see they are asking for sponsorship to get it into shape for release. I've added an answer as to why you would use it instead of ReactTable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[react-table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table) is a "[headless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_software)" UI library which means that it provides only the backend table functionality, and it requires you to implement the rendering of the table with your own React components.

This means that you can apply the backend table code to whichever style of table you want (e.g. Bootstrap, [Material UI](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/material-UI-components), [vanilla HTML](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/basic) etc.) and you get precise control of where to hook-up this library to the UI.

Most table libraries (including react-table pre v7!) have predefined functionality and behaviours which might not be suitable for you in certain cases; however when using react-table >=v7 you would be able to cater for these situations by implementing your own UI code and then hooking it up to your react-table hook code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I think it will make this module more complex.

We have to write the complete code for filters/pagination etc.

Moreover, to manage the UI and CSS is overhead. 

Is there a way to strict with the old one? If yes, is it a good approach?

Please guide.

Comment: You would not need to write the complete code for the filters and pagination as you could make use of the react-table [useFilters](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/api/useFilters.md) and [usePagination](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/api/usePagination.md) hooks. However yes, you would need to manage the UI and CSS of whatever flavour of table markup you choose.